# Power Automate Desktop: Trying to iterate over links in a web table

Tags: datatable, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I hope that someone can put me out of my misery.  I need to open, edit, and submit thousands of links on a site so I thought that I would use power automate.  I have the opening, editing and submitting handled already coded.  The part that is driving me crazy is trying to get a collection of links.  I've seen other people struggling the same way (see [here](https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2024_standings.html#all_standings_EAS)).

In my real project I am working on a site that requires authentication, so I thought I would try to get this working on a public site in the event that someone is kind enough to try it along with me.
https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2024_standings.html#all_standings_EAS

The documentation says that there are multiple ways of doing this.

**1. Get the Datatable**

I was able to inspect and get the datatable from this table

[image]

I got a datatable

[image]

No links available.  Apparently this is only for text.

**2. Get two or more individual links so that PA detects a web table.**

This makes sense, but how do I structure this in PA?  I understand that I would have an entry for each anchor link and they would each have a corresponding variable.  PA then detects that this is a table.  I know how to loop - what am I iterating over?

Answer (score 0):

I see where I was going wrong.  The docs say that if you grab a couple of hrefs that PA will detect that it is a table.  I did not realize that we could do multiple inserts into the web helper - this is where you give it the two examples of Hrefs.

[image]